# hide view parameters in the URL

Tags: jsf-2

We are using JSF 2.0. We have to pass in view parameters from one page to another page as the pages are view scoped. We are getting the values in the params but I would like to know if there is there a way to hide the parameters in the URL?

```
`public String submitForm(){`
 `return "submitPage+faces-redirect=true&includeViewParameters=true&value=" + myBean.id;`
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *to hide the parameters in the URL*

So you want to use POST without redirect? Then just do that accordingly:

```
public String submitForm() {
    return "submitPage";
}
```

In the target page, the `#{myBean.id}` will just be available in EL the usual way.

Comment: myBean.id is not available in the target page because it is view scoped and value is lost when redirecting to target page. To use the bean values in the target page I am passing in the view parameters. My question is related to  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609378/jsf-2-0-view-parameters-to-pass-objects)